# NSEvent: test for only one modfierkey

Tags: cocoa, nsevent, modifier-key

Ok, I understand how to determine from an NSEvent if a modifierkey is pressed :

```
if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask) {
        // The Option/Alt key was pressed
    }
```

But this also captures the optionkey and another modifierkey at the same time, eg Option+Shift, or any combination with the optionkey.

How do I test for *only* the optionkey and nothing else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
const NSUInteger kNotAlt = NSAlphaShiftKeyMask | NSShiftKeyMask | NSControlKeyMask | NSCommandKeyMask;
NSUInteger modFlags = [theEvent modifierFlags];
if (((modFlags & NSAlternateKeyMask) != 0) &&
    ((modFlags & kNotAlt) == 0))
{
    // Only alt was pressed
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll make this into a category for NSEvent and add similar methods for other keys as well.

Comment: Great! If this solved your problem, please click the green checkbox to the left!

Answer (score 4):

You can also try

```
NSUInteger modFlags = [theEvent modifierFlags];
if ((modFlags & NSCommandKeyMask) && !(modFlags & ~NSCommandKeyMask))
{
    // Only alt was pressed
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. In the meantime I also found another, more general solution. I hope the formatting is ok.<br/> `NSUInteger modifiers = [event modifierFlags] & (NSCommandKeyMask | NSAlternateKeyMask | NSShiftKeyMask | NSControlKeyMask);<br/>  if (modifiers == NSAlternateKeyMask)<br/>{<br/> // only alt was pressed<br/>}`